# Wordpress menu item video lightbox

Tags: html, css, wordpress, video, lightbox

I would like to add a button in my wordpress main menu. that when someone clicks on it. 
It will start a lightbox and a video from youtube will play.

Now I was thinking of two possible ways to do that.

1st Add a new div on top of everything with a picture of a button "Play" and when someone clicks on this button to start playing the video in the lightbox (from some plugin)

Or the other way, if possible to add a new menu item (with picture instead of text, and when someone clicks this main menu item, then again the lightbox will appear with the video. Is there anyone who have done something similar?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How comfortable are you editing theme files?

Comment: Very :) I have all access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify per your requirements, this code should add a play icon as a last button in your menu you have to change "main" with your theme_location

```
function addPlayMenuLink($menuItems, $args)
     {
            if('main' == $args->theme_location)
            {
            $class = 'fancybox';
            $url = 'your video url'

            $playMenuItem = '<li>' . $args->before . '<a class="'.$class.'href="' . $url . '" title="play">' . $args->link_before . '<img src= add your play img path />' . $args->link_after . '</a>' . $args->after . '</li>';
            $menuItems = $menuItems . $playMenuItem;
    }
    return $menuItems;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'addPlayMenuLink', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Thank you antonio83! This code should go in functions.php am i right?

Comment: Yes Man! you will also have to modify the class "fancybox" with the one required by the script you are using e.g. pretty photo, colorbox... and add your play image. Let me know if you need any help

Comment: Hello Antonio83. I add the code and the plugin but it doesn't work :(

Comment: Hello, what plugin did you add exactly? could you please post the code with your modification so that I can take a look?

Comment: The first problem is that i don't have a manual menu.
Second i have installed fancybox but still it doesn't work :)

Comment: Ok, what do you mean with I don't have a manual menu? How did you install fancy box? (plugin or you enqueued it in functions.php?) Does fancybox work on other stuff like images? could you please paste the code you modified so that I can take a look? Thanks

Comment: For the menu: I didn't manually create the menu, I created it wordpress dashboard.

FancyBox: I installed the plug-in. I copy your code but i change the picture as you mention and for menu location i put. MAIN menu.

Comment: Ok, I understans a little better, from what you say there can be 3 possible solution: 1) The theme-location value is incorrect, as far as I know it shouldn't be in capital letters. 2) The fancy box plugin has a different call from what I wrote, it may be useful to read the redame or help file and see what it says we might have to modify the code accordingly. 3) I did a typo, I will go trough an old website that needed to add a link to the menu and I will give you that script if that script works for you we know that I did a typo, if it doesn't we know that it is 1 of the other 2 possibilities.

Comment: Allow me 24 hours because I am not in the office and I cannot go trough the old files, It would be helpful if you could link me the exact plugin you are using so that i can take a look and see what to add to the code in order to making it compatible

Comment: Antonio83! Thank you very much. You are very helpful. I will write to you later the link for the plugin i use. Best regards and again thanx

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem in the both way, you mentioned. I do not know which plugins you will use but I think you can use [prettyphoto](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/#prettyPhoto), a jquery plugins. Check it's first example. Just add an image/icon which must be enclosed by a link. However, try it. It will help you.